# peoplePicker memory leak using ARC

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, abrecord

I am using ARC in my project and am being warned of a potential memory leak (see commented lines) on the following. Not sure how to handle it.

```
-( BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker 
  shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier{

ABMultiValueRef phoneProperty = ABRecordCopyValue(person,property);
  // Call to function 'ABRecordCopyValue' returns a Core Foundation object with a +1 retain count

int idx = ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier (phoneProperty, identifier);    

emailToValue= (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneProperty,idx);
  // Object Leaked: object allocated and stored into 'phoneProperty' is not referenced   later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

ARC only manages memory for Objective-C objects, so `phoneProperty` returned by `ABRecordCopyValue` (The `Copy` in the method indicates that it has been retained) needs to be released by your app using `CFRelease`.

Answer (score 2):

No matter if the ARC is used, you both have to handle the CFMemory yourself.
Add the code below before leaving:

```
if (phoneProperty){
CFRelease(phoneProperty);
}
```